# Opencv I want to edit the video frame by frame and save it

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to read the video, edit it frame by frame, and save it as a video again.

For example, I would like to apply Gaussian blur for 1 to 100 frames of 1 minute video, and save the 101 to 200 frames as a single video after saving the midi-blur.

But I do not know how to divide frame by frame after reading video.

If you want to do this, is there a way to save all 1 to 200 frames as an image, then apply the effect and switch back to video?

I found it, but it was hard to find the answer for dividing by frame.

Help me!

Comment: To capture a frame you can use "VideoCapture capture; Mat cameraFeed;
capture.read(cameraFeed);" This will stock the current frame in a the Mat cameraFeed

Comment: what does "dividing by frame" mean?

Comment: Your question is very difficult to understand. Can someone help you make the English clearer so we can help you?

Comment: when reading and decoding the video you always process a single frame. What you do with it is up to you.